# I’ve just brought a Vauxhall Insignia 2012 the steering is not right

Tags: power-steering, vauxhall, insignia

I’ve just brought a Vauxhall Insignia 2012 & I’ve got power steering , but when turning full lock it clonks , also when driving the car it seems to pull to the right sometimes , sometimes it’s fine , could you help me please

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It would seem to me while they are both steering related issues, they are actually being caused by separate things. Have you had the alignment done on the vehicle? Not sure what the "clonk" could be. It might just be how it is designed ... not to make the clonk, but rather there may be a stop which keeps it from turning any further, which may be causing the noise.

Comment: I'd suggest you take this back if it has problems.

Answer (score 1):

A clonk or a clicking noise a clonk could signify a control arm bushing, ball joint or strut plate movement any of which will affect the alignment. If it is more or a clicking noise it would signify a worn out or contaminated half-shaft(front driveshaft) it's best to take to a front end shop and get it properly diagnosed and repaired ignoring for too long will cause more expensive repairs later on.